# How to buy a bus ticket to Reykjavik when arriving to Keflavik airport late at night?

Tags: money, buses, iceland

I will arrive in Iceland at Keflavík International Airport at 23:10, and would like to take a Stræto bus within Reykjavík the following morning at around 07:30.  How might I get hold of the ticket price of 440 ISK in coins?  Advance tickets are sold in packs of 20 only, and on the bus tickets are exact change only (see [Stræto website](https://www.straeto.is/en/upplysingar/spurt-svarad)).  The smallest bill is 500 ISK but an ATM might not dispense anything smaller than 1000 ISK.  Can I exchange bills for coins at night anywhere at Keflavík Airport or in Reykjavík?  Alternately, can I purchase Icelandic coins at currency exchange in Keflavík, so late in the evening?  I think currency exchange usually do bills only, in particular in case I would try to get hold of Icelandic currency before the trip.

Comment: 07:30 is not that early in the morning. Surely there will be some sort of shop open that early, where you can do the usual thing of buying a cup of coffee, candy, etc, and getting change in the appropriate denominations?

Comment: Also, does it have to be coins?  If you can get a 500 ISK note, can you pay with that and simply forfeit the 60 ISK change (which is on the order of USD/EUR/GBP 0.50)?

Comment: @NateEldredge I could.

Comment: You can buy individual bus tickets at the convenience store 10/11. Some of their locations are open 24 hours.

Comment: By the way, **from** the airport to the city you can pay with credit card. Just "tap" and you are on your way!

Comment: @ByronSchmuland I already have a ticket with Flybus from Keflavík Airport to the city — I'm aware that Stræto do take cards for lines outside Reykjavík.  The question relates to the local Reykjavík bus from my accommodation to BSÍ the following morning (I could walk that, really).  Interesting bit of info about 10/11!

Comment: @gerrit Yes my second comment was meant for other travellers. Anyway, enjoy your (too short) visit to Iceland.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland My visit to Iceland is for 2½ weeks but I agree that it's too short.

Comment: The tourist information changed a note to coins for us but your timetable may not fit with theirs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For future reference: You can buy single tickets on the [Strætó mobile app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trapeze.iceland&hl=en_GB) now. Also, [the following shops/kiosks and terminals sell bus tickets and bus cards](https://www.straeto.is/en/verslun/solustadir) (which includes a list of the 10/11 convenience stores mentioned in the comments above).